# Problems addressing WS2812B LED Strip with Raspberry Pi 3 A+

Tags: gpio, pi-4, led, pi-3a+

**Hello!**

I am currently having issues addressing my WS2812B LED-strip correctly with my RPi 3 A+. I have followed the following video guide:
https://forum.core-electronics.com.au/t/problems-addresing-ws2812b-led-strip-with-raspberry-pi/16167

When I am trying to address my LED-strip (GPIO 18), something goes wrong:

- The individual LED’s  lights up, but in random colors.
- Running the same script twice will sometimes lead to different, but still random, patterns.

My dad has a RPi 4 where I just took the SD-card from my RPi 3 A+ and used the same setup and it worked with absolutely no problems.

So why is this?
I am running the same script from the same operating systems, the same power supply (both strip and Pi), and so on...

From what I have read, there is no difference between pins on an RPI 3 and 4.

Details:
I’m using python with packages board and neopixel.

**Thank you in advance!**
**\Mads**